# Laravel Mix with css loaders

Tags: reactjs, webpack, laravel-5.6, webpack-style-loader, laravel-mix

I'm working on a Laravel+React Project. Please how do I configure webpack.mix.js to use css loaders? I have also installed css-loader and style-loader as dev dependencies.

Here's what my webpack.mix.js looks like at the moment:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
  */

mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Why do you want that? Mix already takes care for you.